# SAPUI5 Line Chart (vizframe) Formatter function not found

Tags: javascript, sapui5, linechart, formatter

I want to `format` my `time axis` at the `sapui5 line chart` with a `formatter`. With the following code

```
dimensions: [{
                name: 'time',
                value: "{path:'_time', formatter: '" + Formatter.formatTime + "'}"
            }],
```

appears this error:

```
formatter function function (time) {
        console.warn(time);
        var r = time.toLocaleTimeString();
        return r;
    } not found! -
```

My formatter.js looks like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
], function () {
"use strict";
var me = this;
return {
    splitThingType: function (type) {
        var t = type.split(':')[1];
        return t;
    },

    formatTime: function (time) {
        console.warn(time);
        var r = time.toLocaleTimeString();
        return r;
    }
}
});
```

If I don't use a formatter the chart works but doesn't look that good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach to use formatter in your view. This is how I usually do.

Step 1: 
In your view's controller, define formatter.
 Like:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "yourFormattersPath/formatter"], 
function(Controller, formatter) {
"use strict";
return Controller.extend("com.MyController", {
  formatter: formatter,
  onInit: function(){

  }

 });
```

Step 2: Provide reference in your view where you want to use formatter to format value.

```
dimensions: [{
                name: 'time',
                value: "{path:'_time', formatter:'.formatter.formatTime'}"
            }],
```